# Panel tabbed layout in ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, oracle12c

I have  created a .jsf page containing one panel tabbed component.  The outcome is attached . [image]

Could anyone please tell me how to customise the panel tabbed to get the following structure? i need to increase the width of show detail items in the tabbed layout(**Only the headers are needed**)[image])

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use CSS to customize the look-and-feel of your page.

You could do this by either using the style property or you could build an ADF skin.

See Oracle's documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/b31973/af_skin.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to create ADF Skin. You can use this css to increase tabWidth of panelTabbed

```
af|panelTabbed::tab-content {
    width: 200px; 
}
```